# Screenshot image not showing on Unity UI

Tags: android, screenshot, unity-game-engine

I've implemented that code in my app so the user can take screenshots and save/share it, when I press the camera button the screeshot function is working fine, but the load function is not, I can't see the screenshot taken on my Gameobject.

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SnapshotShare : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AndroidUltimatePluginController androidUltimatePluginController;
    Camera mainCamera;
    RenderTexture renderTex;
    Texture2D screenshot;
    Texture2D LoadScreenshot;
    int width = Screen.width;   // for Taking Picture
    int height = Screen.height; // for Taking Picture
    string fileName;
    string screenShotName = "PictureShare.png";

    void Start ()
    {
        androidUltimatePluginController = AndroidUltimatePluginController.GetInstance ();

    }

    public void Snapshot ()
    {
        StartCoroutine (CaptureScreen ());
    }

    public IEnumerator CaptureScreen ()
    {
        yield return null; // Wait till the last possible moment before screen rendering to hide the UI

        GameObject.Find ("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas> ().enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame (); // Wait for screen rendering to complete
        if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {
            mainCamera = Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera> (); // for Taking Picture
            renderTex = new RenderTexture (width, height, 24);
            mainCamera.targetTexture = renderTex;
            RenderTexture.active = renderTex;
            mainCamera.Render ();
            screenshot = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            screenshot.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
            screenshot.Apply (); //false
            RenderTexture.active = null;
            mainCamera.targetTexture = null;


        }
        if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight) {
            mainCamera = Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera> (); // for Taking Picture
            renderTex = new RenderTexture (height, width, 24);
            mainCamera.targetTexture = renderTex;
            RenderTexture.active = renderTex;
            mainCamera.Render ();
            screenshot = new Texture2D (height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            screenshot.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, height, width), 0, 0);
            screenshot.Apply (); //false
            RenderTexture.active = null;
            mainCamera.targetTexture = null;

        }
        // on Win7 - C:/Users/Username/AppData/LocalLow/CompanyName/GameName
        // on Android - /Data/Data/com.companyname.gamename/Files
        File.WriteAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + screenShotName, screenshot.EncodeToPNG ());  

        // on Win7 - it's in project files (Asset folder)
        //File.WriteAllBytes (Application.dataPath + "/" + screenShotName, screenshot.EncodeToPNG ());  
        //File.WriteAllBytes ("picture1.png", screenshot.EncodeToPNG ());
        //File.WriteAllBytes (Application.dataPath + "/../../picture3.png", screenshot.EncodeToPNG ());
        //Application.CaptureScreenshot ("picture2.png");
        GameObject.Find ("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas> ().enabled = true; // Show UI after we're done
        LoadImage();

    }

    public void ShareImage ()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + screenShotName;
        androidUltimatePluginController.ShareImage("subject","Teste de compartilhamento",path);

    }

    public void LoadImage ()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + screenShotName;
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        LoadScreenshot = new Texture2D(90,90);
        LoadScreenshot.LoadImage(bytes);
        GameObject.Find("Picture").GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = LoadScreenshot;
        Debug.Log("LOAD IMAGE");
    }

    public void close ()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else
         Application.Quit();
#endif
    }
}
```

**The Solution as Gunther Fox said:**

```
 public void LoadImage()
    {

        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + screenShotName;
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        LoadScreenshot = new Texture2D(4, 4);
        LoadScreenshot.LoadImage(bytes);
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(screenshot, new Rect(0, 0, width, height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.0f), 1.0f);

        GameObject.Find("Picture").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;

        Debug.Log("LOAD IMAGE");

    }
```

Comment: Couple of questions : Do you get an error? Do you get the red question mark as texture or nothing? Do you get the LOAD IMAGE to print? Do you have another object named Picture in the scene?

Comment: Hi @Everts, I get no errors, I can see the LOAD IMAGE print and I do not have another Picture object in my scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting the `Texture` of a `Material` on a `SpriteRenderer`; you should be settings [the `sprite` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-sprite.html).  Check out [this Unity doc on creating a `Sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) and then you can apply that knowledge to your situation:

Create a `Sprite` object after loading your texture and then use `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>` to change the `sprite` property. You shouldn't have to change any `Materials`.